# react query infiniteQuery does not fetch next page

Tags: react-native, react-query

Like the title explains, I can't seem to get the next set of results/page on request using react-query infiniteQuery. I also made a snack from their example code but still nothing.

It looks like the pageParam never gets incremented when fetchNextPage is called. I've tried version 3 and 4 with same results.

So I'm not sure if I should be incrementing the nextCursor manually. I can see nothing in the docs that suggests that I have to do so.

[snack example](https://snack.expo.dev/@francot/frisky-edamame)

```
const fetchProjects = async ({ pageParam = 0 }) => {
 const res = await fetch(`https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/passenger? 
 page=${pageParam}&size=10`)
 return res.json()
}

const List = () => {
  const {
  data,
  error,
  fetchNextPage,
  hasNextPage,
  isFetching,
  isFetchingNextPage,
  status,
} = useInfiniteQuery({
  queryKey: ['test'],
  queryFn: fetchProjects,
  getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.nextCursor,
});

const loadMore = () => {
  fetchNextPage()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the API I was using as test does not return any way for me to tell if there is more data to fetch. ie. no `nextCursor` property.